# Stop the user entering ' char

Tags: asp.net, sql, string, validation

I have a search page where I would like to stop the user entering a ' into textboxes, or replace it with a suitable character. Can anyone help me achieve this in asp.net vb ?

For example if a user searches for O'Reilly the search crashes with error:

```
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'Reilly'. Unclosed quotation mark before the character string ' '.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use parameterized statements, and what database you're using?

Comment: If you are using asp.net YOU CAN use parameterized statements

Comment: Time is a factor. I've been allowed time to parameterise after I have a working demo.

Comment: Then don't waste this time on fudging apostrophe handling, because you'll only undo that work when you switch to parameters. Instead, just explain at the demo that you can't search on anything containing an apostrophe yet

Comment: Dim combinator as String = If(andor="0"," AND "," OR ")

Now you can cut your code in half, for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually answer the question, you can put an OnKeyDown javascript event on your textbox, detect the key that was pressed, and potentially cancel the input:

```
<input class="mainSearchBox" type="text" id="searchTerm" onkeydown="DetectIllegalKeys();">

<script>
function DetectIllegalKeys() {
    if (event.keyCode == 222) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

to instead change apostrophes to an alternate character:

```
<input class="mainSearchBox" type="text" id="searchTerm" onkeyup="ChangeSingleQuote();">

<script>
function ChangeSingleQuote() {
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchTerm');
    searchTerm.value = searchTerm.value.replace(/'/g, "e"); 

}
```

I highly recommend that you **not** use this approach for this problem!
Far better to fix the application to allow searches for titles of any character string.

Comment: I'm also guessing for this approach to work, your database will need to store O'Reilly books as OReilly books :-)

Answer (score 7):

Use [parameterized statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements) properly, and this will be handled for you.

Answer (score 2):

Uh-oh. Use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Comment: I can't it is a dynamically generated sql string where some of the rownames are provided via web controls. It is an internal app running behind the firewall, authenticated against AD so users are trusted. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just because users are trusted doesn't mean they won't accidentally create a query that really messes things up....

Comment: @Phil - Even if you're building the statement up in code, you can still put a parameter in the statement at the point where you're currently copying a value in, and add the appropriate parameter to the parameters collection.

Comment: @Phil - also, better hope you're not in that 18% - http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/06/it_attacks_insi.html

Answer (score 1):

You can escape ' character with two of them '', e.g.

```
sql += "Surname LIKE '%" & name.Replace("'", "''") & "%' AND "
```

and SQL will accept it then.

However, I would suggest using [parameters](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Comment: This is subjective (hence no -1) but I'd really, really think twice before even suggesting manual escaping, even if you do point to using parameterized queries then.

Comment: @Pasi: I agree that not using parameters is not best solution, but if Phil doesn't want them, manual escaping will at least give working code. And I think that there is enough warnings in other posts anyhow. :)

Comment: Thanks, Im aware of the warnings and going to action them

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript onKeyDown event for the textbox - if the typed char is an apostrophe, you can simply drop it, so that it is not entered.
On the server side, you should simply replace "'" with "", just to make sure.
Be aware, that this is a very unsecure and unstable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand why the error occurs and not just solve it symptomatically. Read through Microsoft's own document about SQL Injection to find out how to protect yourself from this class of security flaws.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998271.aspx

(As several others pointed out, parameterized statements is the solution.)